# change from deny specific extensions to allow only specific extensions

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net. I have this code:

```
function onSubmitForm() {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    if (formDOMObj.attach1.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach2.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach3.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach4.value == "" )
        alert("Please press the Browse button and pick a file.")
    else
        return true;

    var extension = lcase(right(formDOMObj.attach1.value,4);  
    if (extension == ".exe") || extension == ".html")
        alert("Extension not allowed.")

    return false;
```

}

I'd like to change it to allow only certain extensions instead of excluding them. I can do this by flipping the if but I'd like to change it to work with an array or list but I'm not sure how to do this...

Can someone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - This sounds like you basically want us to do the work for you.

Comment: FYI, if you are doing this for security purposes, this is not an effective method since you are doing everything on the client side.

Comment: k thx, I wasn't aware of that!  And yes Tejs I have tried...I wouldn't have asked for a 'push' in the right direction I would have asked for someone to do it for me instead....thx for caring though.

Comment: I'm going to rethink this then and check it at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if(array.Contains(extension))
```

Comment: This was all I was looking for, it didn't cross my mind to do it this away. Although, I'm going to move it further back towards the server.